# JAVA - GridLayout and JScrollPane behave unexpected

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

My GridLayout in Java behaving diffrently like I expected.

I want to have multiple Boxes within an JScrollPane (like in the screenshot below).

[image]

But when i have to less entries (for example 2) the height of the boxes are 100% height.

[image]

Does someone can tell me what i made wrong in my code?

```java
    ResultSet result = MysqlDataReader.ReadFromDataBase("DUMMY",connectionStrato);
    innerPanel.removeAll();
    innerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(Integer.parseInt(Math.round(result.getRow() / 3) + ""), 6, 2, 2));

    while(result.next()){
        URL url;
        Image image;
        try{
            url = new URL("DUMMY" + result.getString(1) + ".jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
        } catch (MalformatedURLException ex) {
            url = new URL("DUMMY");
            image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
            Logger.getLogger(ItemforList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            url = new URL("DUMMY);
            image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
            Logger.getLogger(ItemforList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        ItemforList item = new ItemforList("DUMMY"+result.getString(1)+".jpg", result.getString(1)+"");
        innerPanel.add(item)

    }
    scrollPaneL.setViewportView(innerPanel);
    Component[] components = innerPanel.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components){
        if(component.getClass().equals(ItemforList.class)){
            ItemforList item = (ItemforList) component;
            System.out.printLn("TEST");
            item.SetResizedIcon();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a question about your code, please post a [mre], not a picture of your code.

Comment: Sorry. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post any code so I can't comment on or directly fix that.

But to answer your question, the way to fix your problem is to fill in the extra grid boxes with dummy components - something just to take up that space